# What is the best option for building a plugin system for a Moose application?

Tags: perl, moose

I want to write a app that can be extended via plugins, using Perl and [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/). I know there are a few Moose modules for writing plugins and I know there are other ways.

What are my options? and what should I know about them? any thing I should think about before implementing a plugin system?

Comment: Have you looked at [Module::Pluggable](http://search.cpan.org/~simonw/Module-Pluggable-3.9/lib/Module/Pluggable.pm)?

Comment: @Len I glanced through different modules at once point, but I'd rather learn from the communities experience. I think I found at least 3 different ones and read about other ways too. I don't know why so many ways exist, and what the difference is. TIMTOWTDI, but usually there is a reason for more than one way existing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to provide extensibility; allow the user to apply roles to your class, or allow them to pass in small objects that do the interesting things (delegates).  Delegates perform better than roles, but will require that you plan for all the extensibility up front. Roles allow more ad-hoc behaviors.

Here are two CPAN distributions that take each approach:

Delegates:  [AnyEvent::Subprocess](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3a%3aSubprocess)

Roles: [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aREPL)

Plugin roles are implemented with [MooseX::Object::Pluggable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aObject%3a%3aPluggable).

Delegates are implemented however you like; the pattern is passing an instance of a class A that does some role R to class C, and then class C delegates to A.  Here's an example:

```
package Compare;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'compare';


package SpaceshipCompare;
use Moose;
with 'Compare';  

sub compare { my ($a, $b) = @_; return $a <=> $b }

package Sort;
use Moose;

has 'comparer' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    does     => 'Compare',
    handles  => 'Compare',
    required => 1,
);

sub my_sort {
    my ($self, @list) = @_;
    return sort { $self->compare($a, $b) } @list;
}
```

Then you use this like:

```
my $sorter = Sort->new( comparer => SpaceshipCompare->new );
my @sorted = $sorter->my_sort("1one", "0", "43");
```

If you want the way Sort works to change, you just create a new class that does the `Compare` role, and then pass an instance to Sort's constructor.  Instant flexibility!

Comment: any chance you know the diff between MooseX::Object::Pluggable and Module::Pluggable?

Comment: @xenoterracide MooseX::Object::Pluggable applies roles to the current class based on a namespace. Module::Pluggable provides a list of namespaces / instances. They are almost entirely different beyond the "look up namespaces" part.

Comment: How does delegation work with including or using packages, do I have to include every possible delegate?