# How do you "lazy load" packages used as delegates?

Tags: perl, oop, delegates, moose

Is there a way I can dynamically include a package based on whatever delegate is used rather than having to include all the various delegates?

I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815432/what-is-the-best-option-for-building-a-plugin-system-for-a-moose-application) on how to use delegates but it glosses over the details I'm trying to understand. The way this is written it's essentially all one file...

```
package Compare;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'compare';


package SpaceshipCompare;
use Moose;
with 'Compare';  

sub compare { my ($a, $b) = @_; return $a <=> $b }

package Sort;
use Moose;

has 'comparer' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    does     => 'Compare',
    handles  => 'Compare',
    required => 1,
);

sub my_sort {
    my ($self, @list) = @_;
    return sort { $self->compare($a, $b) } @list;
}
```

Usage:

```
my $sorter = Sort->new( comparer => SpaceshipCompare->new );
my @sorted = $sorter->my_sort("1one", "0", "43");
```

In my implementation of a delegate I'm using a different resource based on a parameter that's passed to the constructor.

```
  sub BUILD{
    my($this,$args) = @_;

        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'local'){

            $this->setDataStore( Cache::LocalCache->new() ); 

        }

        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'remote'){

            $this->setDataStore( Cache::RemoteCache->new() ); 

        }


        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'memd'){

            $this->setDataStore( Cache::MemedCache->new() ); 

        }

}
```

But in order for this to work I have to

```
use Cache::LocalCache;
use Cache::RemoteCache;
use Cache::MemedCache;
```

Is there a better way to do delegates without perhaps having to use all the packages (like some kind of lazy load)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you can simply use [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

```
sub BUILD{
    my($this,$args) = @_;

        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'local'){
            require Cache::LocalCache;
            $this->setDataStore( Cache::LocalCache->new() ); 
        }

        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'remote'){
            require Cache::RemoteCache;
            $this->setDataStore( Cache::RemoteCache->new() ); 
        }

        if($args->{cachedDataSource} eq 'memd'){
            require Cache::MemedCache;
            $this->setDataStore( Cache::MemedCache->new() ); 
        }
}
```

Since `require` is a run-time operation, the class won't be loaded until it's actually needed.  If your users were passing in class names, then it gets a bit more complicated.  You might want to use [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aLoad) for that.