# How to use Perl Moose with Plugins for a Main Object?

Tags: perl, inheritance, plugins, moose

I'm a newbie in Moose. I have to create an object that should load several plugins. The structure is like this:

- Main Object -> some general Functions
- Plugins  -> extensions for the Main Object

The plugins are in a separate Folder on the server. The Main Object has to load the plugins, initialize them and store the object in itself. Each plugin's return value has to go through the Main Object.  Because the Main Object should transform every return value in a JSON structure for the caller.

I would call something like this:

```
my $main_obj = Main->new();
$main_obj->plugin('MainExtention')->get_title();
```

Here is my example code:

**Main Object:**

```
package Main;
use Moose;

has 'plugins' => (
    is          => 'rw',
);

has 'title' => (
    is          => 'rw',
    isa         => 'Str',
    reader  => '_get_title',
);

# load plugins
sub _load_modules {
  my $self = shift;

    my $path = "/usr/local/apache/sites/.../Plugins";
  push(@INC, $path);

  my @modules = _find_modules_to_load($path);

  eval { 
        my $plugins = {};
        foreach my $module ( sort @modules) {
            (my $file = $module) =~ s|::|/|g;
            (my $modname = $module) =~ s/.*?(\w+$)/$1/;
            require $file . '.pm';
            my $obj = $module->new();
            $plugins->{$modname} = $obj;
            1;
        }
        $self->plugins($plugins);
  } or do {
      my $error = $@;
      warn "Error loading modules: $error" if $error;
  };

}

# read plugins
sub _find_modules_to_load {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    my @files = glob("$dir/*.pm");

    my $namespace = $dir;
    $namespace =~ s/\//::/g;

    # Get the leaf name and add the System::Module namespace to it
    my @modules = map { s/.*\/(.*).pm//g;  "${namespace}::$1"; } @files;

    return @modules;
}

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_load_modules();
}

sub get_title {
    return 'main title'
}

1;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

**Plugin MainExtention in directory "/usr/local/apache/sites/.../Plugins":**

```
package MainExtention;
use Moose;

has 'title' => (
    is          => 'rw',
    isa         => 'Str',
    default     => 'Default',
);

sub get_title {
    return 'MainExtention Title';
}

1;
```

This works like this:

```
my $main = Main->new();
my $plugins = $main->plugins();
print $plugins->{'MainExtention'}->get_title();
```

But this is not what I will have :) I will get the return of the plugin not directly from the plugin but from the Main Object. Does anyone have an idea?
Second question: is there a simpler way to get the plugins loaded? How?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301959/dynamically-loading-perl-modules

Answer (score 1):

To load plugins, I'd recommend using [Module::Pluggable](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aPluggable), which can load a bunch of packages from a directory and instantiate them (or not) as you need.

If you need to have the main object wrap the plugin, just define a method on the main object to do whatever you need:

```
package Main;
use Moose;

# Adds a plugins() method to Main that returns a list of all loaded plugin packages
use Module::Pluggable search_dirs => [ "/usr/local/apache/sites/.../Plugins" ];

# Used to store the plugins after ->new is called on each package
has loaded_plugins => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'HashRef[Object]',
    lazy_build => 1,
    traits => [ 'Hash' ],
    handles => { _plugin => 'get' },
);

# Constructor for loaded_plugins, implied by lazy_build => 1
sub _build_loaded_plugins {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my %loaded_plugins;
    for my $plugin ($self->plugins) {
        $loaded_plugins{$plugin} = $plugin->new;
    }

    return \%loaded_plugins;
}

# Method for getting the processed title from any plugin
sub get_plugin_title {
    my ($self, $name) = @_;

    my $plugin = $self->_plugin($name);

    my $title = $plugin->get_title;

    # process the title according to whatever Main needs to do...
    ...

    return $title;
}
```

Then, your code:

```
my $main = Main->new();
print $main->get_plugin_title('MainExtension');
```

If you're using Moose, I might also suggest making all of your plugins implement a [role](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aRoles), which can help you discover if the plugin has been implemented properly.

Comment: Thank you for your support! That helps me a lot! Module::Pluggable with search_dirs does not work. I dont know why. After i tested it with search_path and that looks good!


`use Module::Pluggable require => 1, search_path => 'Main::Plugin';`


In the next step i will implement roles.